# Duplication of Records due to join a table

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

As stated in the title, There are record duplications when I try to join a table

let say the main below table is called "Customer"

| Month_id | customer_name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202012 | A | 10000 |
| 202012 | B | 569 |
| 202012 | C | 23000 |

the 2nd table is called "Date"

| Year | Month_id | Time_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201201 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201202 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201203 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201204 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201205 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201206 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201207 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201208 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201209 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201210 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201211 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201212 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201213 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201214 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201215 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201216 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201217 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201218 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201219 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201220 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201221 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201222 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201223 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201224 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201225 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201226 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201227 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201228 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201229 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201230 |
| 2020 | 202012 | 20201231 |

I tried to join both of them to get the year
( NOTE: I know that I can use substr function to extract the year from mont_id, but I do not want to do that because that was just an example)

```
select a11.month_id, a11.Customer_name, a11.Amount, a12.year
from customer a11
join Date a12 on a11.month_id = a12.month_id
```

The result that I expect from the above query is the following
[image]

unfortunately, I got duplications in rows instead of that. to be more clarified I got 31 records for each customer

EX: Customer A

[image]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please post data as formatted text, instead of images? This would help people to try a query on your sample data

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT DISTINCT ...` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group the dates by month; an easy way could be:

```
select a11.month_id, a11.Customer_name, a11.Amount, a12.year
from customer a11
join
(
    select month_id, year
    from Date
    group by month_id, year
) a12
on a11.month_id = a12.month_id
```

Another way, without modifying the join part, could be by simply using `DISTINCT`

```
select distinct c.Month_id,c. customer_name, c.Amount, d.year
from customer c
inner join dateTable d
on c.month_id = d.month_id
```

But notice that this strongly relies on the fact that you just have one row for each customer and month; otherwise you could need to `SUM` the amounts and things change

Comment: Thank you, it is useful, due to using Microstrategy I can not modify the join table it will be always as it is. However, I am looking for another way to modify the "customer" table to fix this issue. what do you think ?

Comment: Just showed a way, but pay attention to the constraints